# com.apple.timezone.auto.plist moved in 10.14

Tags: macos, terminal, date, time-zone, macos-mojave

In previous version of macOS you use to be able to toggle turning on and off the "Set time zone automatically using current location" from terminal by use this

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.timezone.auto.plist Active -bool TRUE
```

Is seems in Mojave (10.14.2) the plist has move or no longer exists. I tried to manually create the plist in that location but it's ignored by the system. Does anyone know where the plist is stored now if it is at all? Is there a different way to change that setting now from the command line or is it now blocked entirely by Apple's new security updates?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo systemsetup setusingnetworktime on` (or `off`) seems to do the trick, but it also toggles "Set date and time automatically" as part of this.

Comment: I did come across this when looking for an answer. When I tested it the GUI in System Preferences > Date & Time > Time Zone was not updating the check box like the plist update way was so I was unsure if it was actually turning it on and off.

Comment: @Dash Okay, I've been working on this for a while with no luck. As far as I can see, the prefpane isn't writing to a file when the box is check/unchecked, which makes me think it's running some command that does the actual work. One option would be to use osascript to run a Applescript GUI script from the command line, but I'd like to think there's a better way. Hopefully I'll have a better answer for you by Sunday.

Comment: Yeah same here i have been trying to figure an easy way to replace what that did in my post. I will try writing an osascript now and see if that works. Only issues with that is that I know that Movjave has may block system events from running. I am trying to figure out a way for user without admin right the ability to enable "Set time zone automatically using current location" and then syc the current time